# Flask and Nova glance download: TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

Tags: python, flask

I am having a head-heck with a piece of code.
I am developing an Openstack Nova driver, which needs at some point to download a Glance image to a remote server. This remote server hosts a Flask web server which has a REST API to allow content to be downloaded (POST /api/images/pull).
When I try the code, I get the following error: "TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()".

Here is the code on the Nova side:

```
def pull_image(self, image_obj, context, image_href):
    # Put the Glance image to the Wparrip server
    (image_service, image_id) = glance.get_remote_image_service(context,image_href)
    read_iter = image_service.download(context, image_id)
    image_size = image_obj.get_image_size(context, image_href)
    headers = {
         'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
         'Content-Length': image_size,
         'Transfer-encoding':'chunked',
         'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
         'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
         'X-Meta-Glance-Image-Id': image_href
    }
    def _get_next():
        for chunk in read_iter:
            if chunk:
                yield chunk

    resp = self._make_request('POST','/api/images/pull',headers=headers, body=_get_next())
    if resp.code != 200:
        raise Exception(_("Cannot create_container %s") % format(resp.code))
    return True
```

And here is the code on the Flask server side:

```
@app.route('/wparrip/api/images/pull', methods = ['POST'])
@crossdomain(origin='*')
def image_download():
    """
    The other way around... we download an image coming from
    Glance (or another source __future__). 
    """
    local_filename="test.tgz"
    file = os.path.join(image_local,local_filename)
    f = open(file, 'wb')
    while True:
        data = request.data
        if data:
            f.write(data)
            f.flush()
        else:
            f.close()
            break
    resp = make_response(jsonify( {'file':file} ), 200)
    return resp
```

So, here is the _make_request function:

```
def _make_request(self, *args, **kwargs):
    headers = {}
    if 'headers' in kwargs and kwargs['headers']:
        headers = kwargs['headers']
    if 'Content-Type' not in headers:
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        kwargs['headers'] = headers
    rest = httplib.HTTPConnection(self._host_ip,self._host_port)
    if rest is None:
        raise Exception(_("Cannot create the Http remote Connection"))

    rest.request(*args, **kwargs)
    return rest_utils.Response(rest.getresponse())
```

Does anyone can help me figure out what is wrong in this piece of code?

Here is the error log on nova side (Flask side is not interesting, except that we do pass in the piece of code I sent)

```
    2014-02-21 15:46:55.101   [00;32mDEBUG glanceclient.common.http [  [00;36m-  [00;32m]   [01;35m  [00;32mcurl -i -X HEAD -H 'X-Service-Catalog: [{"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://10.197.160.95:8776/v1/174a21dd0de043719d87c7c9e2f9d062", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://10.197.160.95:8776/v1/174a21dd0de043719d87c7c9e2f9d062", "id": "11b750f23e9b4c36bb9d1948cdfb0ad6", "publicURL": "http://10.197.160.95:8776/v1/174a21dd0de043719d87c7c9e2f9d062"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "volume", "name": "cinder"}]' -H 'X-Identity-Status: Confirmed' -H 'X-Roles: admin' -H 'User-Agent: python-glanceclient' -H 'X-Tenant-Id: 174a21dd0de043719d87c7c9e2f9d062' -H 'X-User-Id: 451d46cd619243668658c92f8a1a29a4' -H 'X-Auth-Token: af6606b8713d09b2f85b308098e4c7d7' -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' http://10.197.160.95:9292/v1/images/b408d525-3186-4200-a9a7-90eaf756b843  [00m   [00;33mfrom (pid=836) log_curl_request /opt/stack/python-glanceclient/glanceclient/common/http.py:142  [00m
2014-02-21 15:46:55.121   [00;32mDEBUG glanceclient.common.http [  [00;36m-  [00;32m]   [01;35m  [00;32m
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 0
x-image-meta-id: b408d525-3186-4200-a9a7-90eaf756b843
date: Fri, 21 Feb 2014 14:46:55 GMT
x-image-meta-deleted: False
x-image-meta-checksum: 3a106675dfc12795963726e7b9cf53b0
x-image-meta-container_format: wparrip
x-image-meta-protected: False
x-image-meta-min_disk: 0
x-image-meta-created_at: 2014-02-03T20:17:24
x-image-meta-size: 505
x-image-meta-status: active
etag: 3a106675dfc12795963726e7b9cf53b0
location: http://10.197.160.95:9292/v1/images/b408d525-3186-4200-a9a7-90eaf756b843
x-image-meta-is_public: True
x-image-meta-min_ram: 0
x-image-meta-owner: 174a21dd0de043719d87c7c9e2f9d062
x-image-meta-updated_at: 2014-02-03T20:17:24
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
x-openstack-request-id: req-8413d18f-a4d1-486c-b846-f47c92b39e8e
x-image-meta-disk_format: raw
x-image-meta-name: testwpar
  [00m   [00;33mfrom (pid=836) log_http_response /opt/stack/python-glanceclient/glanceclient/common/http.py:152  [00m
2014-02-21 15:46:55.121   [00;32mDEBUG nova.virt.wparrip.client [  [01;36mreq-62be8844-136e-4fe0-a431-7ecc02e87758   [00;36madmin admin  [00;32m]   [01;35m  [00;32mwparrip, pull_image=505  [00m   [00;33mfrom (pid=836) pull_image /opt/stack/nova/nova/virt/wparrip/client.py:292  [00m
2014-02-21 15:46:55.122   [01;31mERROR nova.compute.manager [  [01;36mreq-62be8844-136e-4fe0-a431-7ecc02e87758   [00;36madmin admin  [01;31m]   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [01;31mInstance failed to spawn  [00m
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00mTraceback (most recent call last):
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m  File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1434, in _spawn
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m    block_device_info)
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m  File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/virt/wparrip/driver.py", line 287, in spawn
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m    res = self._session.pull_image(_image, context, instance['image_ref'])
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m  File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/virt/wparrip/client.py", line 307, in pull_image
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m    resp = self._make_request('POST','/wparrip/api/images/pull',headers=headers, body=_get_next())
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m  File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/virt/wparrip/client.py", line 152, in _make_request
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m    rest.request(*args, **kwargs)
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 958, in request
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 992, in _send_request
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m    self.endheaders(body)
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m    self._send_output(message_body)
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 818, in _send_output
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m    self.send(message_body)
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 790, in send
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m    self.sock.sendall(data)
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/greenio.py", line 309, in sendall
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m    tail = self.send(data, flags)
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/greenio.py", line 291, in send
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m    len_data = len(data)
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00mTypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
  [01;31m2014-02-21 15:46:55.122 TRACE nova.compute.manager   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00m
2014-02-21 15:46:55.124   [00;32mDEBUG nova.compute.claims [  [01;36mreq-62be8844-136e-4fe0-a431-7ecc02e87758   [00;36madmin admin  [00;32m]   [01;35m[instance: d22e3fbb-2035-4b4f-a89c-37656adc4a12]   [00;32mAborting claim: [Claim: 1 MB memory, 0 GB disk, 1 VCPUS]  [00m   [00;33mfrom (pid=836) abort /opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/claims.py:107  [00m
2014-02-21 15:46:55.124   [00;32mDEBUG nova.openstack.common.lockutils [  [01;36mreq-62be8844-136e-4fe0-a431-7ecc02e87758   [00;36madmin admin  [00;32m]   [01;35m  [00;32mGot semaphore "compute_resources"  [00m   [00;33mfrom (pid=836) lock /opt/stack/nova/nova/openstack/common/lockutils.py:167  [00m
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: Generators don't have a length (`len()`) indeed.

Comment: I have updated the post to add the logs.

Comment: I can't find the error (the one mentioned in the title) in your traceback.

Comment: Sorry, wrong cut/paste, I have edited again with the right log.

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with the call to `self._make_request`. Are you sure you can pass a generator as the `body ` argument?

Comment: Ok, I updated the thread to show you the _make_request. Note that this function works great otherwise.

Comment: So, nobody can help me solve this issue?

Comment: ok, after refactoring some code ... it appears that ow the trouble is with Flask not supporting chunked transfer...too bad for me.